# Except a primary key constraint with on insert, using _mssql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, exception, primary-key

MSSQL 2005 Server (IIRC) and Python module _mssql.. I have multiple inserts to a table with a single row, which is the primary key.. Now it is possible that I insert the same value multiple times, but I want to simply ignore the **"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint"**. Other errors should be raised.

I'm aware that I can `try: [...]INSERT[...] except: *magic*: pass` but I couldn't find the exception's name which occurs..

edit:

I don't know whether this solution is acceptable but it's what I've got so far.

```
try:
    con.execute_query('INSERT [...]')
except _mssql.MssqlDatabaseException,e:
    if e.number == 2627:
        #primary key constraint
        pass
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to ignore the primary key? Have you heard about normalization?

Comment: I need to ignore the error, that is raised in python, as this script may attempt to insert existing values due to performance reasons.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an UPSERT - which means update if it exists, or insert. As you are using a very old version of SQL Server, try this:

```
q = """IF EXISTS (SELECT PrimaryKeyField FROM SomeTable WHERE PrimaryKeyField = %s)
    UPDATE SomeTable
        SET
            SomeFieldA = %s,
            SomeFieldB = %s,
            SomeNumberA = %d
        WHERE
            PrimaryKeyField = %s
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO SomeTable (
            PrimaryKeyField,
            SomeFieldA,
            SomeFieldB,
            SomeNumberA
        ) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%d)"""

cur.execute(q, ('a','b','c',1,'a','b','c',1))
con.commit()
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but as stated earlier any updates or checks whether the key already exists or not slow down the process and in my situation, unfortunately, it is unacceptable. So I'd need to ignore the error, as it doesn't add anything anyways in this case.

Comment: Please understand - primary keys are very important. You think its slow now? Wait till you start to query it and your keys are not accurate.

Comment: yes I understand. The processing with this table has to be as fast as possible. non-unique primary keys are tried to be written multiple times (but are not written to the database ~ key constraint exception).. the filled table is later merged to a new table where they will be handled as they should.